# How can I tell what version of Java my programs are running on Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, java

Want to have something that lists java VMs running on the system and which programs these are hosting. In particular which tomcat is using which java version. IS there any command line tool that I can use on debian like systems?

---

For tomcat specifically I've found :

```
ps uax | grep tomcat
```

which gives the full command line that includes path to the java vm used, however is there a more  java oriented way of getting a comprehensive listing?

Answer (score 3):

If properly installed using the `update-java-alternatives`, you can find them by issuing:

```
# update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-gcj-4.6 /usr/lib/jvm/java-gcj-4.6
java-gcj-4.7 /usr/lib/jvm/java-gcj-4.7
jdk1.7.0_03 7003 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_03
```

Otherwise, if only installed with the plain `update-alternatives` system, use:

```
# update-alternatives --display java
```

If you just drop JREs/JDKs anywhere, you will have to parse the output of something more targeted than

```
# ps -def | grep java
```

Something similar with regards to Tomcat. If you installed Tomcat using the repositories, the file `/etc/default/tomcat{6,7}` contains a `JAVA_HOME` variable that points to the JRE/JDK used by this instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -version
```

Also, run a file on `/etc/alternatives/java`. That will show the location of the binary.